# Canon 1000D and sigma ef-610 flash issues

Tags: flash, sigma, ttl, canon-1000d

I have a canon 1000D DSLR and a Sigma EF-610 flash. The Flash seems to work find in full Auto mode when attached to the camera body,  but when I try to use it off camera I run into problems.

When the flash is off camera and connected with my (allegedly) ETTL cable, with the flash on either auto or either manual mode, the camera reports an FE Lock warning, and refuses to take a picture.

The cable is labelled TTL-C, and was sold as a canon ETTL cable.

I assume that the issue is with the cable (i.e. that it isn't actually an ETTL cable) but I wanted to double check with the experts here that it wasn't actually a problem with the flash (or the camera).

Answer (score 1):

When attached with a working E-TTL cable the flash should behave exactly as if it were connected directly to the hot shoe. One thing you may want to check is the alignment of the connections at both ends of the cable. Make sure the cable is inserted all the way into the hot shoe and that the flash is inserted all the way into the other end of the cable. And of course be sure you don't have either end connected backwards! (It is fairly easy to insert the flash into the cable the wrong way.) If the pins and contacts aren't lined up properly then nothing will work.

Comment: I did do my best to ensure that cables were both connected the right way round and anchored - I will check again. Is a TTL-C cable the same as a E-TTL cable ? I couldn't find any information.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 if the pin/contact layout matches the Canon pin/contact lay out, it's a Canon eTTL cable (as well as a Fuji X and micro four-thirds TTL cable :). Understand that there are five separate lines inside the cable, any one of which could be bad.